# How to write Triggers in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

In sqlserver 2008, i write trigger like this but i am little bit doubt that it is wrong can you check this once.

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[UST_RollPlan_History_Trigger]
           on [dbo].[Tbl_F_Roll_PlanDetails_T] for INSERT as
    insert into Tbl_F_Roll_PlanDetails_H
                (rollingplanid, productcode, rollplanmonthyear,
                 rollplanyear,  candflocation, quantity, amendedqty,
                 createdby, createdon, sessionid, status)
    select       rollingplanid, productcode,rollplanmonthyear,
                 rollplanyear, candflocation,quantity,amendedqty,
                 createdby, createdon, sessionid, status
    from         Tbl_F_Roll_PlanDetails_T
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you listed any errors you might be getting (what makes you "doubt"?), and format the query - I would recommend http://poorsql.com (but then I run it :)).

Comment: @rubens farias when i replace the Tbl_F_Roll_PlanDetails_T with inserted at the  end of the triger now the triger is working fine is it the fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *typically*, in a trigger, want to reference the `inserted` (and/or `deleted`) pseudo-table, that contains the rows which were affected by the operation. I expect you want this:

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[UST_RollPlan_History_Trigger]
           on [dbo].[Tbl_F_Roll_PlanDetails_T] for INSERT as
    insert into Tbl_F_Roll_PlanDetails_H
                (rollingplanid, productcode, rollplanmonthyear,
                 rollplanyear,  candflocation, quantity, amendedqty,
                 createdby, createdon, sessionid, status)
    select       rollingplanid, productcode,rollplanmonthyear,
                 rollplanyear, candflocation,quantity,amendedqty,
                 createdby, createdon, sessionid, status
    from         inserted
```

which will insert rows that have just been inserted into `Tbl_F_Roll_PlanDetails_T` into the `Tbl_F_Roll_PlanDetails_H` table. (Incidentally, prefixed names in SQL are generally pointless, since the types of objects that can appear in any particular context are either a] already limitied to a single type of object, or b] should not need to be distinguished anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Please check trigger examples at the following tutorial, [SQL Server Triggers](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-trigger-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)
Triggers are powerful but developers should be very carefull while using triggers. Because many developers think it will work once for each effected row but triggers work only once.